# how to add a variable to a textarea (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm working on my MERN application, where it includes a textarea. I want to let the user add the variable in between the text template. Eg., [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRNfm.png)

How can I achieve this logic using React and Node JS?

Comment: you should use `contenteditable` div

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, the string received on the backend is:

```
let email = "Hi John, I hope you are doing good".
```

Now, to retrieve the name **John**, we can do something like this:

```
let indexOfSpace = email.indexOf(" ");
let indexOfComma = email.indexOf(",");
let name = email.substring(indexOfSpace, indexOfComma);
```

You can study about these methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp).

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being clear. Actually, I want my user to add a variable in textarea. (Eg., Like an email template, where the client name, date will be dynamically changed)

Comment: The best way to do it is to first let the user fill in all the required details and then on submission, manipulate the content of the text area, and set the value of the required variables.

Comment: Yeah, but since it's a template, The sending of email and getting the username is handled by the backend. The textarea is stored as a string in the database, how exactly can I manipulate it back then?

Comment: Thank you for your participation, but the email string tends to change depends on diff user. so we are not sure of the variable position.

Comment: I know, this is not a complete solution, it's just a way to do it.